# Python: List index out of range for hash table program

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, hash

Not sure if this code works and it shows index out of range which I don't know how to solve

```
class Hash():

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.max = user
        self.table = []

    def isFull(self):
        if len(self.table) == self.max:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def insert(self,item):
        if self.isFull():
            print('Hash table is full')
        else:
            hashing = self.index(item)
            if self.table[hashing] == None:
                self.table[hashing] = item
            else:
                for a in range(len(self.table)):
                    if self.table[a] == None:
                        self.table[a] = item
        return self.table

    def index(self,item):
        hashval = int(item) % self.max
        return hashval


    def searching(self,item):
        pass

user = int(input('Enter a number for the maximum number of items that can be stored in the hash table: '))
```

It says index is out of range due to -> if self.table[hashing] == None:

Comment: just had a task to make a hash table

Comment: `self.table` is always an empty list in your code.  There are no valid indexes that can be used to access it.

Comment: If you want a list full of `None` with a specific length, you have to define it that way: `self.table = [None] * self.max`

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using list instead of dict. You should replace `self.table = []` with `self.table = {}`
2. `if self.table[hashing] == None:` will raise an error if `hashing not in self.table`. You should replace it with: `if hashing not in self.table:`
3. `for a in range(len(self.table)):` will not iterate through `self.table` because it is not a list. `for a in self.table:` will work.

Here is the correct code:

```
class Hash():

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.max = user
        self.table = {}

    def isFull(self):
        if len(self.table) == self.max:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def insert(self,item):
        if self.isFull():
            print('Hash table is full')
        else:
            hashing = self.index(item)
            if hashing not in self.table:
                self.table[hashing] = item
            else:
                for a in self.table:
                    if self.table[a] == None:
                        self.table[a] = item
        return self.table

    def index(self,item):
        hashval = int(item) % self.max
        return hashval


    def searching(self,item):
        pass

user = int(input('Enter a number for the maximum number of items that can be stored in the hash table: '))
h = Hash(user)
h.insert(5)
h.insert(6)
```

Comment: thanks it works but then it doesn't fill in the next available slot when the hash values are equal

Comment: Updated the answer.